# How to use SwitchCompat?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbaractivity, switchcompat

I have a `ActionBarActivity`. In it I create a list by using `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter`. In it I try to use `SwitchCompat` :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/sampleSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON"
    android:text=""
    android:clickable="true"
    android:checked="true" />
```

But something goes wrong...

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.util.LruCache
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:53)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:471)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:93)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.loadClassFromModuleOrDependency(ProjectClassLoader.java:108)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:89)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:56)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.<clinit>(TintManager.java:42)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getTintManager(TintTypedArray.java:182)
at android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.<init>(SwitchCompat.java:213)
at android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.<init>(SwitchCompat.java:171)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:374)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:99)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:575)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:564)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:564)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:691)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:604)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1900(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:546)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:541)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

This is my application theme :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackGroung</item>

    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

and my dependencies :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'}
```

I have no actions on SwitchCompat in my java code. Please, show me my mistake.

Comment: find the solution. I can't use <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat in xml. I need to create it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the solution. I can't use `<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` in xml. I need to create it programmatically.

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), R.style.AppTheme);
SwitchCompat sc = new SwitchCompat(ctw);
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutLightsItem);
linearLayout.addView(sc);
```